# Catching exceptions thrown by Python properties assigned by Factory

Tags: python, exception

Given the following setup, I need to try to create a `MyClass` instance and log *every* Exception that the @property setters throw (not just the first one).

```
class MyClassFactory(object):

    def __init__(self, data):

        d = {
            "age": sanitize(data, 'age'),
            "name": sanitize(data, 'name')
        }

        for (k, v) in d.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

        mc = MyClass()

        for prop in self.__dict__.items():
            try:
                # assign value to MyClass instance
            except MyException as e:
                raise


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._age = None
        self._name = None

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, age):
        if age != '':
            try:
                self._age = int(age)
            except ValueError:
                raise MyException
        else:
            raise MyException

    # similar property for `name`
    # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = loadjson()

    for record in data:
        f = MyClassFactory(record)
```

I could do it like below, however I have many more properties. How do I

1. set `MyClass` properties based on the attributes of `MyClassFactory` and
2. Log all exceptions, not only the first one that gets thrown?

---

```
try:
    mc.age = self.age
except MyException as e:
    raise
try:
    mc.name = self.name
except MyException as e:
    raise

# ... many more
```

Answer (score 1):

The MyClass class can catch all the exceptions in setter methods, and store them in a '_exceptions' list/dict variable belonging to MyClass.

Your factory class can then verify that this list/dict is empty. If not, you can access all the exceptions in this one place.